# Angular - Display data from 2 JSON in HTML

Tags: html, json, angular

I'm having trouble displaying data from 2 interconnected JSON in Angular.

First JSON:

```js
member = [
  { id: 1, name: 'shinta'},
  { id: 2, name: 'rahma'},
  { id: 3, name: 'john'}
]
```

Second JSON:

```js
nest = [
  {id: 1, amount: 2000, userid: 1},
  {id: 2, amount: 3000, userid: 2}, 
  {id: 3, amount: 5000, userid: 2},
  {id: 4, amount: 1500, userid: 1},
  {id: 5, amount: 2200, userid: 1},
  {id: 6, amount: 12500, userid: 1},
  {id: 7, amount: 7000, userid: 2}, 
  {id: 8, amount: 8300, userid: 3}, 
  {id: 9, amount: 2800, userid: 3},
  {id: 10, amount: 9500, userid: 3}
]
```

How to view/bind data in HTML?

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of memberData, let i = index">
  <li>{{ item.name }} <span>*this to view sum of user amount*</span></li>
</ul>
```

Please guide me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: you are rendering data on memberData where is the memberData in your ts? add that snippet as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `.map()` to create new array with:

- Duplicate object element of `members` (via `...x`)
- New field: `totalAmount` with `.reduce()` to perform aggregate sum.

```js
this.memberData = this.member.map((x) => ({
  ...x,
  totalAmount: this.nest
    .filter((y) => y.userid == x.id)
    .reduce((total: number, current) => (total += current.amount), 0),
}));
```

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of memberData; let i = index">
  <li>
    {{ item.name }} <span>{{ item.totalAmount }}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jy6jcc?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. now my problem solve because you. :)